# A list of operators in the For cycle

Tags: functions, operators, procedural-programming

I'm pretty sure that analogous questions have been asked here a zillion of times, but...

I think it is pretty straightforward from the code what I expect it to give:

```
oplist[] := Module[{op, list = {}, k},
   For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++,
    AppendTo[list, Function[x, x^k]];
    ];
   For[k = 4, k <= 5, k++,
    AppendTo[list, Function[x, x^k]];
    ];
   Return[list];
   ];
list = oplist[];
For[k = 1, k <= Length[list], k++,
  Print[list[[k]][a]];
 ];
```

Instead of `a, a^2, a^3...` I have `a^6, a^6, a^6...`
I guess, it's something about pointers/links/evaluating at the moment when smth is called.

I tried replacing `x^k` with `x^Evaluate[k]`, but this does not help either.

Comment: Try this: f[x_] := x^Range[5]  This gives a list of the functions you appear to want. If you want t evaluate at a, then f[a] gives your list {a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5}.

Comment: Or if you need them to be operators then `oList = With[{k = #}, #^k &] & /@ Range@5` which can then be invoked with `Through@oList@a `.

Answer (score 1):

```
Attributes[Function]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected}

That is, *all arguments to* `Function` *are to be maintained in an unevaluated form*. So `x^k` in  `Function[x, x^k]` is not evaluated unless it is wrapped with `Evaluate`:

```
ClearAll[k, x, a, oplist]
oplist[] :=  Module[{op, list = {}, k}, 
   For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++, 
    AppendTo[list, Function[x, Evaluate[x^k]]];];
   For[k = 4, k <= 5, k++, 
    AppendTo[list, Function[x, Evaluate[x^k]]];];
   Return[list];];

list = oplist[];
For[k = 1, k <= Length[list], k++, Print[list[[k]][a]];];
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `With[{j = k}, AppendTo[list, Function[x, x^j]]]` in place of  `AppendTo[list, Function[x, Evaluate[x^k]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

just remove k from

```
 Module[{op, list = {}, k}
```

this will get it right. no other changes in your code

```
oplist[] := 
Module[{op, list = {}}, 
For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++, AppendTo[list, Function[x, x^k]]];
For[k = 4, k <= 5, k++, AppendTo[list, Function[x, x^k]]];
Return[list]]
list = oplist[]
For[k = 1, k <= Length[list], k++, Print[list[[k]][a]];];
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it happens like that? In general, should I never list cycle indices inside the list of local objects? Will they not interfere with the indices defined outside of the Module?

Comment: k is defined inside For... Why do you use 2 For-loops instead of one?

Comment: The question arises from a more general context, where different cycles inside Module cannot be combined into one, and the outcome of the procedure so far depends on order of cycles inside it.

Comment: Please see my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185136/using-the-value-of-the-variable-in-the-definition-of-the-function).