# Using the value of the variable in the definition of the function

Tags: functions

How do I take the current value of `n` in the second line in order for the answers to be the same in both cases?

```
n = 2;
f[x_] := x/n;
Print[f[8]];
n = 4;
Print[f[8]];
```

Now:

```
4
2
```

Want:

```
4
4
```

Basically, I want the function to be `x/2` after my definition. (Please don't suggest defining it as `x/2`, I need to define a list of functions inside the cycle.)

**UPDATE**

The question I asked looks oversimplified, so suggested solutions do not really work for me. Here is a more realistic example.

I want to create a list of functions, each acting on a complicated argument:

```
ft = {};
For[n = 1, n <= 3, n++,
  tmp[x_] := x[[1]]/n;
  AppendTo[ft, tmp];
  ];
ft[[1]][{12, 1}]
ft[[2]][{12, 1}]
ft[[3]][{12, 1}]
```

The generated output is

```
3
3
3
```

The desired output is:

```
12
6
4
```

I cannot replace `:=` with `=` since this produces an error.

Comment: Either use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` (so that it will immediately evaluate `f[x]` to be `x/2`), or else make `n` part of the argument list to `f`.

Comment: Could you please show how I should use `Set` in this case?

Comment: this returns 4 and f[] , not 4 and 2

Comment: Sorry! I have fixed.

Comment: Kinda like in the documentation: `f[x_] = x/n;` (not `:=`)

Comment: how about  f[x_] := Block[{n = 2}, x/n]

Comment: Ohhh... for some reason I though `f[x_] = x/n;` is a 'bad' way to do things... (in terms of how `x` will be treated)

Comment: How can I use the `Block` method inside a `For` cycle with its index being `n`?

Comment: Please see the updated version of the question.

Comment: @mavzolej Why for your example not just use `{12,1}[[1]]/Range[3]`? Seems a lot of hassle with the for loop and a list of functions just to divide by a list of different numbers.

Comment: Again, this is a very simplified version of what I really need to do. In my project, I have to defined numerous operators/functions inside numerous `For` cycles. And the particular form of these operators is dependent on the cycles' indices. Besides that, I'm really shocked that getting the value of the variable is so damn hard in Mathematica. I was actually hoping to get the resolution with the aid of `Evaluate`, but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Almost surely your statement "I have to define numerous operators/functions inside numerous For cycles" is false. I would really suggest that you take some time to learn the basic syntax of the language -- you will see that there are likely many better ways of defining such complex structures. Said another way, you are approaching your problem in a very roundabout way.

Comment: This may be true, but still, the inability to extract the immediate value of the variable is somewhat shocking news...

Comment: Here's the problem with your code: look at ft // FullForm and you will see that the list you have built is: List[tmp,tmp,tmp]. So when you evaluate this you get three copies of the latest value of tmp, which is 3. If you write meaningless code, it returns nonsensical answers. Nothing shocking about that.

Comment: I know exactly how it works. That's why I was asking for an improvement on this friendly forum.

Comment: You can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to inject the values into an otherwise held expression: `With[{n=n},f[x_]:=x/n]`. But as others have pointed out, a `For` loop is never (or very rarely) the proper solution in Mathematica. If you could provide a more complete description of what you're trying to accomplish, one could help you to find a more efficient solution for the whole problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is much better to use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table) to construct a list instead of using [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For) and [`AppendTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo). Second, in order to inject the value of `n` into your function definition, you need to use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With). Finally, instead of defining `tmp` 3 times (so that each definition overrides the previous definition), you can define `tmp[n]` 3 times. Putting this together we have:

```
ft = Table[
    With[{n=n},
        tmp[n][x_] := x[[1]]/n;
        tmp[n]
    ],
    {n, 3}
]

ft[[1]][{12,1}]
ft[[2]][{12,1}]
ft[[3]][{12,1}]
```

> {tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3]}
>
> 12
>
> 6
>
> 4

**Address OP question**

When you use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed), this means that the RHS is *not* evaluated when the definition is created. Example:

```
n=3;
f[x_] := x/n
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x/n}

Notice how the definition has `n` instead of `3`.  In order to get the value of `n` inserted into your definition you need to use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) (although there are many cases where you can't use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set)) or you need to use a method to insert the value of `n`, a common one being [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With):

```
With[{n = 3},
    f[x_] := x/n
];
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[x$_]] :> x$/3}

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Could you please clarify what exactly does `{n=n}` inside `With` gives us in this case?